# Wordpress: Container doesn't take full width when in responsive view

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I've been reading the tips here for a long time and received a lot of help. Today I am in the need of individual help...

The responsive view (< 1024 px) should be full-width and centered with a little padding. The padding works fine, but the content doesn't fulfill the whole page with a big margin on the right. I tried all of the css tweaks listed here. The actual custom css code is:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
#boxed, html, body, div.container.main-content
{
width:      100% !important;
margin:     0px;
}
.row
{
margin:     0px !important;
width:      100% !important;
padding:    15px !important;
}
.container, .container-wrap
{
margin:     0px !important;
width:      100% !important;
padding:    0px !important;
}
}
```

The website is www.timschuermann.com/dev/

Thank you for your help in advance

Tim

**Update 1**

Thank you for your quick answers! I tried all the suggestions, it still doesn't work.

The actual code is:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
div.container.main-content
{
width:      100% !important;
margin:     15px auto !important;
}
#boxed, html, body
{
width:      100%;
margin:     0px;
}
.row
{
width:      100%;
margin:     0px;
padding:    0px;
}
.container, .container-wrap
{
margin:     0px;
width:      100%;
padding:    0px;
}
}
```

The actual design is exactly the one I got "out-of-the-box".

I want the content to be displayed bigger, with a 15px margin left and right.

But there is also a new problem: On my iPhone there is blank room, colored grey, above the content. After reloading it goes away?

I hope you understand what I mean and can help me.

Thanks in advance

Tim

Comment: Word of advice, stop using `!important`, its not needed if your stylesheet is cascading correctly

Comment: Overwrite your max-width with 'max-width: inherit;'

Comment: There are FOUR different CSS rules in the `responsive.css` file that contain several `max-width` settings  - on lines. And they all contain `important`.  Just check the CSS in the browser inspector while having the page in a narrow window, then you'll see those settings.

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid using `!important`. It will give you are hard time when you need to change your stylesheet later on.

To center the container please add the following.

```
div.container.main-content {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Too many "!important" is not needed is causes css overiding issues.
But to fixes yur current issue you have to uses "!important" because of previous uses on the same element

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
div.container.main-content {
    width: 100% !important;
    margin: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;/**Added This **/
}
}
```

But will advised to revise your code when you have the time, to removed unnecessary ones. hope this helps.